# HABTM join doesnt produce any results from associated array in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to link a HABTM model with joins but I dont get any records from the joined tables.
I have data for the tutor id =2 and also I have this id of 2 in the other tables of tutors-subjects and also a key in the subject. i should not get NULL in the other tables. I dont get an error.

I want all the subjects for tutor id =2.

Here is the controller and model with the relationship

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Subject' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'name' => null
        ),
        'TutorsSubject' => array(
            'id' => null,
            'tutor_id' => null,
            'subject_id' => null
        ),
        'Tutor' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'tutor_inactive' => false,
            'first_name' => 'fred2',
            'last_name' => 'blah',..........

    class TutorsController extends AppController {

     public function tutordetails() {
                $options2['joins'] = array(
                   array('table' => 'tutors_subjects',
                    'alias' => 'TutorsSubject',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                    'Tutor.id = TutorsSubject.tutor_id', //fixed 'Tutor.id = TutorsSubject.id', //
                     )
                     ),

                    array('table' => 'subjects',
                    'alias' => 'Subject',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                    'TutorsSubject.subject_id=Subject.id',
                     )
                     )

                ));

                 $options2['fields'] = array('Subject.*','TutorsSubject.*','Tutor.*');

                $this->Tutor->recursive = -1;
                $options2['conditions'] = array('Tutor.id'  => 2);
                $subject=$this->Tutor->find('all',$options2);
                $this->set('subject', $subject);
                debug($subject);


    class Subject extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(

        'Tutor' => array(
            'className' => 'Tutor',
            'joinTable' => 'tutors_subjects',
            'foreignKey' => 'subject_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'tutor_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',

        )
    );

}

    class Tutor extends AppModel {
        ..

        public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Subject' => array(
                'className' => 'Subject',
                'joinTable' => 'tutors_subjects',
                'foreignKey' => 'tutor_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'subject_id',
                'unique' => 'keepExisting',
                'conditions' => '',

            ),

        );

UPDATE=AgRIZZO solved it and changed made above
```

Comment: you have used `$this->Tutor->recursive = -1;` that prevent fetching records from its associated models.

Comment: find the details here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

Comment: No that didnt fix the problem !as I get no records with different recursive value.Yes I am aware of the recursive argument and I get no asociated records regardless of what I set recursive to.yes I have read the docs.

Comment: where is the information on joins because I am asking a basic question and still getting it wrong as this doesnt explain things in joins area http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: If you set up the HABTM within the models correctly, you do not need to use JOINs for the above question.  You should try a simple `find` to start (code is for your TutorsController):
`$this->Tutor->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Tutor.id' => 2)));`  What does the results of this return?

Comment: I get all the records if I remove the recursive =-1. I really want to use joins so could you or someone please tell me why my join doesnt work. I have been trying for hours .

Comment: In fact I canty get the subjects field when running the above find all from #AgRizzo  .   My join cant be too far wrong surely and i cant get the answer from past posts.

Comment: IMO: Using JOINs when you have properly defined model relations is huge mistake. Use the framework for what it was defined for (and you need is well supported without the JOINs.). That being said - your problem is most likely this: `'Tutor.id = TutorsSubject.id'` in your first JOIN definition.  Try `'Tutor.id = TutorsSubject.tutor_id'`

Comment: OK you got it working .  Excellent work!I spent too long on it and made a simple mistake. Now taking your advice how can I get it to work without joins as the find you gave didnt find the associated models which is also defined in the question.

Comment: AgRIZZo place you code in the answer so i can mark it as you deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

Agrizzo had the answer  Using JOINs when you have properly defined model relations is huge mistake. Use the framework for what it was defined for (and you need is well supported without the JOINs.). That being said - your problem is most likely this: '

Tutor.id = TutorsSubject.id' in your first JOIN definition. Try

```
        'Tutor.id = TutorsSubject.tutor_id
```